# Setting up a LAMP server with ReactJS

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, rest, lamp

I've been having a rough time trying to set up a LAMP web server with a ReactJS application. I haven't found anything conclusive on the web.

So, in my /var/www/html/ folder I have the following:

- backend (folder)
- static (folder)
- asset_manifest.json
- manifest.json
- service-worker.js
- favicon.ico
- index.html

Except the backend folder, the rest are just ReactJS files resulting from doing a production build inside WebStorm. The backend folder has the following structure:

- media (folder with photos);
- public (index.php file which contains only imports);
- src (folder which contains two more folders, config and routes. Config helds the db connection file and the routes folder contains the REST services written with the Slim framework);
- other files required for the Slim framework (composer.json, vendor folder, etc.)

Now, the ReactJS application works, but when I try to login, it throws a 404 not found error when calling the REST API. I have no idea how to solve this.

I've written an .htaccess file in the index.php folder which has this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If you have any ideas on how to solve this, please let me know. I'm really struggling. Thank you! :D

Comment: Ideally you should not combine php and reactjs code into a same directory, however make sure your php rest api are runing well and returning the expected response, you can use postman tool to carry out test for server endpoints,  The HTTP 404 Not Found Error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server. It is a Client-side Error which means that either the page has been removed or moved and the URL was not changed accordingly, or that you typed in the URL incorrectly, you can please share more details so that I can propose you a detailed  solution.

Comment: So, on my Windows machine I set up a xampp installation which had the backend folder inside the htdocs folder. Then, in a separate folder, I have the frontend, which is a webstorm project. When starting xampp and do an npm start inside Webstorm, all the REST services are working properly. After that, the next step was to put both part together on a Linux machine with LAMP installed. So here I am now